# Submit формы через ajax

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Пользуюсь вызовами $.ajax... и вот возник вопрос, а нет ли метода, типа .submit(), только который будет не сабмитить форму и перезагружать страницу, а через ajax все данные из формы отправлять на указаный action, и потом получать данные от сервера в функцию?

```
<script>
function myCallback(data) {
...
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="url" id="myform">
<input>....
</form>
```

скажем $('#myform').send('myCallback');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не так, это просто отправка данных через ajax, а я говорил про сабмит формы. Решение уже нашел, плагин jquery.form.js

```
$('#myform').ajaxSubmit({
success: function(data)
{
alert(data); 
}
});
```

Данные берутся из формы, url из action

Answer (score 2):

```
var $form = $("#myform");

$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    type: $form.attr("method"),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        console.log("It's OK");
    }
})
```

Так? (При желании можно вынести всё это в отдельную функцию)